eval: command not found
I have next script:
a.sh:
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    eval "$@"
else
    eval '"$@"'
fi

b.sh:
echo "para1: $1"
echo "para2: $2"
echo "para3: $3"

When I do next, both with quote or without, they are ok:
$ ./a.sh "./b.sh '1 2' '' 3"
para1: 1 2
para2:
para3: 3
$ ./a.sh ./b.sh '1 2' '' 3
para1: 1 2
para2:
para3: 3

But when I change the command to next, the one which without quote reports error:
$ ./a.sh "A=1 ./b.sh '1 2' '' 3"
para1: 1 2
para2:
para3: 3
$ ./a.sh A=1 ./b.sh '1 2' '' 3
./a.sh: line 4: A=1: command not found

How can I manage it work for both?
Please note: I should let b.sh treat '1 2' as the first parameter, '' as the second, while 3 as the third parameter, this is the reason I add '' around $@ in a.sh.

Since you put quotes around each argument with "$@", "A=1" isn't a variable assignment, it's a command name. And there is no such command.

I think you shouldn't try to make it work for both cases, it results in ambiguities.

eval may not be the best way to implement whatever it is you're trying to do, you might want to ask a new question about whatever that is.

See Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead? and BashFAQ/048 (Eval command and security issues).


How can I manage it work for both?

Just:
"$@"

No eval no nothing. And then use env to set a variable:
./a.sh env A=1 ./b.sh '1 2' '' 3

Or call shell when you want to execute shell, all 3 are equivalent:
./a.sh bash -c 'A=1 ./b.sh '\''1 2'\'' '\'\'' 3'
./a.sh bash -c "A=1 ./b.sh '1 2' '' 3"
./a.sh bash -c 'A=1 "$@"' -- ./b.sh '1 2' '' 3


a.sh :
eval $@
# other process
echo "A = $A"

b.sh is unchanged
but you should use semicolon to separate commands and use it like this:
user@computer:~$ ./a.sh A=5; ./b.sh '1 2' '' 3
A = 5
para1: 1 2
para2: 
para3: 3


Unquoted $@ is always pointless, and almost always wrong; as it is in this answer.  See Accessing bash command line args $@ vs $*.
